# If $V=M_{n \times n}(C)$ and $T \in L(V)$ defined by: $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $V=M_{n \times n}(C)$ and $T \in L(V)$ defined by: $T(A)=\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$, then
>
> a)Verify that $T$ is a linear operator
>
> b) Conclude that $T$ is a projection
>
> c) What are the subspace $W_1=Im(T)$ and $W_2= Ker(T)$, conclude that $V= W_1\oplus W_2$
>
> d) Can we see what $rank(T) $ and $null(T)$ are? Note that $rank(T)+ null(T) = n^2$ in this case.

For **part (a)** what I have to check is that $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$ is still a $n \times n$ matrix?

I think **Part (b)** is easy, I have to check that $T = T^2$

I need more details for **Part (c)** and **Part (d)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually $W_1 = \{M\in V:M\text{ is symmetric}\}$. Note that $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^t)$ is symmetric. It suffices to show that every symmetric matrix lies in $W_1$. It is easy, since $T(A) = A$ if $A$ is symmetric. It is also easy to find that $W_2 = \{M\in V:M^t = -M\}$, and that $W_1\cap W_2 = \{0\}$. Hence $W_1+W_2$ is a direct sum.

We first calculate $\dim W_1$ and $\dim W_2$.

For $W_1$, the independent variables are the diagonal and the entries above the diagonal. Thus there are $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ independent variables and so $\dim W_1 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

For $W_2$, the diagonal must be $0$, and hence the independent variables should be the entries above the diagonal. Thus $\dim W_2 = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Therefore, $\dim V = \dim W_1+\dim W_2$. This implies $V = W_1\oplus W_2$.